# Can't create branch TFS 2008 - Error 8152

Tags: sql, branch

I'm trying to create a new development branch from main (our first branch) but with no luck.
I've tried google but google doesn't seem to want to help me today...

The error i receive is this:

```
A database error occurred (SQL error 8152) ---> String or binary data would be truncated.

SRV-TFS.TfsVersionControl..prc_PendBranch: Database Update Failure - Error 8152 executing INSERT statement for tbl_PendingChange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check the name of your branch. I think its too long that TFS database allows.